# from_dropdown get text from table row

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu

```
<table id="dataTable" width="300px" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="width: 130px">
                <?php
                $js = 'id="country" style="width: 130px;"';
                echo form_dropdown('country', $country, set_value('country'), $js); ?>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>



$('#sent').bind('click', function(){ 
    var table=document.getElementById("dataTable");
    for(var i=1; i<table.rows.length;i++){
        var country =  table.rows[i].cells[1].children[0].value;
    }
 });
```

I get null for var country after select from dropdown. The table consist of multiple row.
Any solution for this? I have to get the text return from the country downdown.

Answer (score 0):

You're already using jQuery, why not jQuery it again:

```
$('#sent').bind('click', function(){ 
    console.log( $('#dropdownMenu').val() ); // if you have one
    // if you have multiple
    $('.dropdownMenus').each(function(){
        console.log( $(this).val() );
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried this is able to get for the first row but second row table how to get?

Comment: Updated my answer a bit, you can use each() for that

Comment: how to put into my table.rows count? pls assist

Comment: It's allowed to test/check for yourself. The code is exactly how you can use this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree you can use jquery but if you actually want to know how to do it using javascript here it is:

`var = document.getElementById('country').options[document.getElementById('country').selectedIndex].text`
where country is the name of your drop down list.

Just for completeness here is the jquery solution as well. 
`var = $("#country option:selected").text()`
Choose whichever suits you best

Using either of these will grab the text in the dropdown box.  Hope this helps :)

Comment: can it be multiple? i having multiple dropdown in my table row.

Comment: If you mean can you have multiple drop downs then yes, just call them what you want and grab them using jquery 1 after the other.  If you mean can you grab multiple selected items from one dropdown box then you can use Martijns code :)

Comment: A quick note about Martijns code just so it isnt too confusing what hes doing.  His example has multiple drop downs all with a class called '.dropdownMenus' and that code will go through them one at a time and grab the selected text. Edit: Sorry cant put this comment with Martijns code as I dont have enough reputation points yet :(